# Pandas Latitude-Longitude: Calculate the distance between two points and select the nearest one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, coordinates, distance

I have a dataframe with 15k rows with coordinates and the names of the locations (mainly businesses)

| spot | lat1 | l1 | place | lat2 | lon2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41,1808128356934 | -8,53291034698486 | A | 41.146749 | -8.613889 |
| 1 | 41,1808128356934 | -8,53291034698486 | B | 41.146105 | -8.609868 |
| 2 | 41,1491432189941 | -8,61034202575684 | A | 41.146749 | -8.613889 |
| 2 | 41,1491432189941 | -8,61034202575684 | B | 41.146105 | -8.609868 |

I've been trying to perform a subtraction between both coordinates to find the distance (in meters) and then select only the the spot and place with less distance between them.

This is the code I was trying to use:

```
df['X_diff'] = df['lon1'] - df['lon2']
df['Y_diff'] = df['lat1'] - df['lat2']
df['dist'] = np.linalg.norm(df[['X_diff', 'Y_diff']], axis=1)
```

I also realized that the type of coordinates were different.

```
spot     object
lat1     object
lon1     object
place    object
lat2     float64
lon2     float64
dtype: object
```

How do I find the distance and select only the nearest one?

Comment: You can use the `haversine` formula in case the distance is too big and earth curvature comes into the picture.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I read about it and was able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lat1` and `lon1` are strings. Maybe you want to replace `,` with `.` and convert to float before you calculate the norm:

```
df[['lat1', 'lon1']] = df[['lat1','lon1']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.replace(',','.')) )
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried and had the error `ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime.` Don't know why it's assuming is a datetime?!

Comment: @LuisFerreira My bad, it should be `pd.to_numeric`. No idea I put `pd.to_datetime` :D

Comment: my bad to not checked that :D Thnak you again :D